# Prove Convergence with ratio test for series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\prod_{i = 1}^{n} = \frac{i}{2i-1}) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> I am examining the limit of the following series:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\prod_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{i}{2i-1}\right).$$
>   According to the solution, by using the ratio test for series, I would get
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left|\prod_{i = 1}^{n+1} \frac{i}{2 i - 1 }\right|}{\left|\prod_{i = 1}^{n}  \frac{i}{2 i - 1}\right|}
> = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{n+1}{2(n+1)-1}\right|.
> $$ 
>   I do not know, how I can get from the fraction of the left side to the fraction on the right side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\frac{\left|\prod_{i = 1}^{n+1} \frac{i}{2 i - 1 }\right|}{\left|\prod_{i = 1}^{n}  \frac{i}{2 i - 1}\right|}
= \frac{\left| \frac{1}{2 - 1} \cdot\frac{2}{4 - 1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n}{2n - 1} \cdot \frac{n + 1}{2(n +1) - 1} \right|}{\left| \frac{1}{2 - 1} \cdot\frac{2}{4 - 1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n}{2n - 1} \right|}
$$ 
The numerator has the same terms as the denominator, except one, so all terms cancel except the last one, which is the one your are left with.

Also, since all terms are positive, you can ignore the absolute values.

Answer (score 4):

Does it help?
$$
\frac{\left|\prod_{i = 1}^{n+1}\frac{i}{2i-1}\right| }{\left|\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{i}{2i-1}\right|}
= \frac{\left|\frac{n+1}{2(n+1)-1}\right|\left |\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{i}{2i-1}\right| }{\left|\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{i}{2i-1}\right|}
= \left|\frac{n+1}{2(n+1)-1}\right|
$$